# Difference between innerText and html

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the the difference between `innerText`, `text()`, and `html()`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`innerText` (or [`text()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text) if you're using jQuery) doesn't include any HTML tags. So if you had a div that contained:

```
View my <a href="profile.html">profile</a>
```

`innerText` / `text()` would return

```
View my profile
```

while `html()` would return

```
View my <a href="profile.html">profile</a>
```

As dcneiner points out `html()`/`text()` are jQuery properties (and supported across browsers) while innerText is not implemented by all browsers (although it works in the most recent versions of IE, Safari, and Chrome).

Basically you'll want to use `text()` isntead of innerText whenever possible. See [**dcneiner's** post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1836958/662581) (or the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text)) for some other things that make `text()` awesome.

Comment: Does the fact that `innerText` is an IE only property and has nothing to do with jQuery mean anything? :)

Comment: I seem to be able to use *innerText* all the time. For reasons that are beyond my control, I'm not able to use jQuery. Is it **then** wrong to go for *innerText*? What bad can happen? (I'm asking this because I see that the current reply is a bit dated and new things may have happened since then.

Comment: FireFox still doesn't support `innerText` (it uses `textContent`). If you can't use jQuery just take that into account. See here for a list of compatible browsers http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html.

Comment: For reference, `textContent` is specified in DOM Level 3, and is supported by all major browsers, including IE9+.  (For IE8, i'm sure there's a shim somewhere.)  It's slightly different than `innerText`, but (IMO) in good ways.

Answer (score 11):

The difference is that `innerText` is an IE only property on a DOM object and `html()` is a function of the jQuery object.

However, if you were comparing `text()` and `html()` then the difference is that `text()` strips all HTML from the contents of an element before returning and `html()` includes includes the HTML.

Additionally, `text()` will return the text of **all** matched elements and concatenate them together:

```
<span>Hi, </span><span>how are </span><span>you?</span>

$("span").text(); // returns: Hi, how are you?
```

But `html()` will only return the first matched items `innerHTML` property:

```
$("span").html(); // returns: Hi,
```

One last cool thing, is that `.text()` auto escapes all HTML:

```
$("span:first").text('<a>Hi</a>'); // writes &lt;a&gt;Hi&lt;/a&gt;
```