# How to get value from contentEditable div in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, richtextbox, contenteditable

I'm trying to create a very simple contentEditable div input.  However, any way that I can think of to get the value of the input is not exactly what the user typed in IE because whitespace is collapsed.  i.e. "hello  world" becomes "hello world".  But it's important to me that I be able to get the text as the user has typed it if at all possible.  Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: I don't see this behavior in ie8. How are retrieving the content of the div? Can you provide more details?

Comment: I tried innerText, innerHTML, and everything else I can think of in IE 8.  How were you able to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I can get the value just fine using innerHTML without IE collapsing any spaces.  However, there is no way to set the value such that IE doesn't collapse spaces, which makes it absolutely impossible to unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to read the innerHTML from the div?

Comment: Yes, it does not work.

<html>
  <body>
    <div id="test">hello              world</div>
 <script>
   alert(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML);
 </script>
  </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Use the good old "&nbsp;" and it will work as you want ;)

Answer (score 0):

For your example did you try innerText, I'm just afraid that using innerHTML might return some added markup that some browsers might add when manipulating the editable content.

Check this stackoverflow questions for difference between innerHTML and innerText:

[Difference between innerText and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836942/difference-between-innertext-and-html)